What is the principal n-th root of a complex/real number?
When taking the square root of a real number, we take the principal (positive) value. For example, if we have:
$$
\sqrt{x} = y \in (0, \infty) \implies y^2 = x
$$
Additionally, we know that:
$$
\sqrt{x^2} = |x|, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
This is quite straightforward. But what happens when we want to take the n-th root of a real number? For instance, is the statement $\sqrt[3]{-1} = -1$ true?
In the complex plane, for $z^n = w$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the general solution is given by:
$$
z_k = \sqrt[n]{|w|} e^{i \left( \frac{\arg(w) + 2k\pi}{n} \right)}, \quad k \in \{0, 1, \dots, n-1\}
$$
Thus, the principal root corresponds to $k=0$, and we can express the n-th root as:
$$
\sqrt[n]{z} = \sqrt[n]{|z|} e^{i \frac{\arg(z)}{n}}
$$
For example:
$$
\sqrt[3]{-1} = e^{i \frac{\pi}{3}}
$$
Is this the correct interpretation, or am I missing something?

Correct, the principal root is not -1 but $e^{i\pi/3}$: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeRoot.html. The principal value of the $n$-th root of $re^{i\phi}$ is $r^{1/n}e^{i\phi/n}$, so the principal square root of a positive number is positive ($\phi=0$), and the principal cube root of a negative number is $r^{1/3}e^{i\pi/3}$.
